# Inconsistent tag suggestions: `comma` -> `command-line`; `comman` -> `command`; `command` -> `command`

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-tags

**Note to close voters**: the tag suggestion algorithm is the same for all Stack Exchange websites, this is why I'm posting the question here even though my example is from https://unix.stackexchange.com (that's just one example).

---

Inconsistent tag suggestions:

- `comma` -> `command-line`
- `comman` -> `command` (`command-line` isn't even in the list of tag suggestions)
- `command` -> `command` (`command-line` the #2 tag suggestion)

See screenshots below from https://unix.stackexchange.com:

[image]

[image]

[image]

gif:

[image]

Comment: I understand `command`, since it's an exact match, but the other two don't really make any sense. Maybe favor the shorter one.

Comment: I don't understand the two community-specific close votes. The algorithm is the same for all 
Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: One of the close reasons says it can no longer be produced. I just tried to produce it and I couldn't reproduce it as well. I only noticed the third outcome (command -> command), but I assume that happens because the whole word matches the tag. Also, maybe comma -> command-line happens because command-line has more posts with that tag?

Comment: so far I have only noticed that a different tag rises to the top of the suggestions when it is an exact match for the current value of the textbox.